# XPath fails when using XmlUtil (UFT 12.0)

Tags: xpath, vbscript, xml-parsing, hp-uft

Given the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <WFContext xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/entity/message/2003/" soapenv:actor="" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
      <messageId>cci-sf-dev14.wellsfargo.com:425a9286:14998ac6245:-7e1e</messageId> 
      <sessionId>425a9286:14998ac6245:-7e1d</sessionId> 
      <sessionSequenceNumber>1</sessionSequenceNumber> 
      <creationTimestamp>2014-11-10T00:14:49.243-08:00</creationTimestamp> 
      <invokerId>cci-sf-dev14.wellsfargo.com</invokerId> 
      <activitySourceId>P7</activitySourceId> 
      <activitySourceIdType>FNC</activitySourceIdType> 
      <hostName>cci-sf-dev14.wellsfargo.com</hostName> 
      <billingAU>05426</billingAU> 
      <originatorId>287586861901211</originatorId> 
      <originatorIdType>ECN</originatorIdType> 
      <initiatorId>GTST0793</initiatorId> 
      <initiatorIdType>ACF2</initiatorIdType> 
    </WFContext>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <getCustomerInformation xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/provider/ecpr/customerProfile/inquiry/getCustomerInformation/2012/05/">
      <initiatorInformation xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/provider/ecpr/shared/common/2011/11/">
        <channelInfo>
          <initiatorCompanyNbr xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/entity/message/2003/">114</initiatorCompanyNbr>
        </channelInfo>
      </initiatorInformation>
      <custNbr xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/entity/party/2003/">287586861901211</custNbr>
      <customerViewList xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/provider/ecpr/customerProfile/inquiry/getCustomerInformationCommon/2012/05/">
        <customerView>
          <customerViewType>GENERAL_INFORMATION_201205</customerViewType>
          <preferences>
            <generalInformationPreferences201205 xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/provider/ecpr/customerProfile/inquiry/common/2012/05/">
              <formattedNameIndicator xmlns="">true</formattedNameIndicator> 
              <includeTaxCertificationIndicator xmlns="">true</includeTaxCertificationIndicator> 
            </generalInformationPreferences201205>
          </preferences>
        </customerView>
        <customerView>
          <customerViewType>SEGMENT_LIST</customerViewType> 
        </customerView>
        <customerView>
          <customerViewType>LIMITED_PROFILE_REQUIRED_DATA</customerViewType> 
        </customerView>
        <customerView>
          <customerViewType>INDIVIDUAL_CUSTOMER_GENERAL_INFORMATION_201205</customerViewType> 
        <preferences>
          <individualGeneralInformationPreferences xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/provider/ecpr/customerProfile/inquiry/common/2012/05/">
            <includeMinorIndicator xmlns="">true</includeMinorIndicator> 
          </individualGeneralInformationPreferences>
        </preferences>
        </customerView>
      </customerViewList>
    </getCustomerInformation>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to access the `getCustomerInformation` tag using relative XPath in VBScript.

```vbs
XMLDataFile = "C:\testReqfile.xml"
Set xmlDoc = XMLUtil.CreateXML()
xmlDoc.LoadFile(XMLDataFile)
Print xmlDoc.ToString
'xmlDoc.AddNamespace "ns","xmlns:soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
Set childrenObj = xmlDoc.ChildElementsByPath("//*[contains(@xmlns,'getCustomerInformation')]")
msgbox childrenObj.Count
```

But is failing to return a node.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression does not work because `xmlns` as in

```
<getCustomerInformation xmlns="http://service.wellsfargo.com/provider/ecpr/customerProfile/inquiry/getCustomerInformation/2012/05/">
```

is a *default namespace*, not an attribute. Therefore, it cannot be accessed with `@xmlns`.

But it seems you do not have to rely on the namespace at all, because the element name ("getCustomer Information") is telling already. To bypass the problem of those elements being in a namespace, use `local-name()` to select elements by their name.

```
Set childrenObj = xmlDoc.ChildElementsByPath("//*[local-name() = 'getCustomerInformation']")
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Mathias Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884049/1630171) already explained in his answer, `xmlns` defines a namespace and can thus not be accessed like a regular attribute. I don't have experience with XmlUtil, but in standard VBScript you could select the node(s) like this:

```vbs
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.async = False
xml.load "C:\path\to\your.xml"

If xml.ParseError Then
  WScript.Echo xml.ParseError.Reason
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

'define a namespace alias "ns"
uri = "http://service.wellsfargo.com/provider/ecpr/customerProfile/inquiry/getCustomerInformation/2012/05/"
xml.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns='" & uri & "'"

'select nodes using the namespace alias
Set nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//ns:getCustomerInformation")
```